# JWPlayer in MVC3 application does not work when deployed in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7.5, jwplayer

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 application with c# and Razor. I created a page where the user can **play video files** which are located in the application directory tree.

When I tested the application locally it was working correctly, when I deployed it in **MS Server 2008 with IIS 7.5** everything worked fine except the video streaming.

The page does not even display the player and this let me think that the application cannot find the Javascript file needed to load the player. I tried all the types of URL encoding, I set different types of permission but that did not solve the problem. Hereby I post the code of the **View**:

```
 @model System.String

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Play";
}

<h2>Playing Topic Video</h2>

<div id='player'>This div will be replaced by the JW Player.</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='@Url.Content("/FLV Player/jwplayer.js")'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

   var filepath = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

   jwplayer('player').setup({
   'flashplayer':'@Url.Content("/FLV Player/player.swf")',
   'width': '400',
   'height': '300',
   'file': filepath
   });
</script>
```

Where **Model** is a string representing the **path** of the video file. May anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@Url.Content("/FLV Player/player.swf")
```

You should:

```
@Url.Content("~/FLV Player/player.swf")
```

Notice the `~`. This is what you are missing in both your urls. Always put a `~` in the beginning when you are using the `Url.Content` helper. It will represent the virtual directory name.